# filter data from an array of objects based on another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, filter

I have any array of objects:

```
array1 = [
    {id: "1", policy: "abc", date: "20-05-2019" },
    {id: "4", policy: "hjk", date: "12-05-2019" },
    {id: "5", policy: "ikl", date: "08-05-2019" },
    {id: "7", policy: "qwe", date: "20-05-2019" },
    {id: "8", policy: "bdd", date: "04-05-2019" },
]
```

I have another large array like this:

```
array2 = [
 {
   "info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "qwe", },
   "date" : { "sDate" : 20-05-2019, "eDate" : 20-06-2019 }
 },
 {
   "info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "ikl", },
   "date" : { "sDate" : 20-05-2019, "eDate" : 20-06-2019 }
 },
{
   "info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "bbb", },
   "date" : { "sDate" : 20-05-2019, "eDate" : 20-06-2019 }
 },
{
   "info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "bdd", },
   "date" : { "sDate" : 04-05-2019, "eDate" : 20-05-2019 }
 },
];
```

I want to compare all policy field & date field in array1 with array2 (assume array2 is very large).
then, create array of objects if policy field (array1) matches with insuredPolicy (array2) & date field in array1 matches with sDate in array2

so output will be:

```
array3 = [
{ policy: "qwe", date: "20-05-2019" },
{ policy: "bdd", date: "04-05-2019" },
];
```

In learning phase, any help will be really appreciated.

**EDIT**

How to compare if array2 contains sDate one day ahead? If so, then reduce sDate by 1 day and then compare. How can we achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use filter and Map

1. Since you mentioned second array is very large so searching every time through complete array increase time complexity
2. So map the second array into a key,value pair using Map
3. Filter values from array1 based on values present in Mapper

```js
const array1 = [{id: "1", policy: "abc", date: "20-05-2019" },{id: "4", policy: "hjk", date: "12-05-2019" },{id: "5", policy: "ikl", date: "08-05-2019" },{id: "7", policy: "qwe", date: "20-05-2019" },{id: "8", policy: "bdd", date: "04-05-2019" },]

const array2 = [{"info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "qwe", },"date" : { "sDate" : '20-05-2019', "eDate" : '20-06-2019' }},
{"info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "ikl", },"date" : { "sDate" : '20-05-2019', "eDate" : '20-06-2019' }},{"info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "bbb", },"date" : { "sDate" : '20-05-2019', "eDate" : '20-06-2019' }},{"info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "bdd", },"date" : { "sDate" : '04-05-2019', "eDate" : '20-05-2019' }},];

const mapper = new Map(array2.map(({
  info,
  date
}) => [info.insuredPolicy, date.sDate]))

const final = array1.filter(({
  policy,
  date
}) => {
  if (mapper.has(policy)) {
    return mapper.get(policy) === date
  }
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: A small edit required in question, need to reduce sDate one day & then compare with date. eg: if sDate is 05-05-2019, then reduce one day and compare with date in array1.

Comment: @Vishnu parse date using new Date and manipulate in desired manner, or if you project has lots of date related operation use a standard library like moment or date-fns

Comment: can you please update with moment or date-fns? It will be very helpful.

Comment: @Vishnu with all due to respect you must try first atleast once, if you still face you can ask here, you will learn by doing yourself, give it a try once and let me know if you still face a difficulty, happy coding

Comment: Yes sure, can you please let me know whey used Map here? I didn't get the point.

Comment: @Vishnu search time is O(1) in Map where as in array it will be O(n), even if it sorted it will be O(log n) using binary search, Map is used to improve time complexity

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Array#filter` on array1 with `Array#some` on array2 to filter out the required elements.

```js
const array1 = [{id: "1", policy: "abc", date: "20-05-2019" },{id: "4", policy: "hjk", date: "12-05-2019" },{id: "5", policy: "ikl", date: "08-05-2019" },{id: "7", policy: "qwe", date: "20-05-2019" },{id: "8", policy: "bdd", date: "04-05-2019" },]

const array2 = [{"info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "qwe", },"date" : { "sDate" : '20-05-2019', "eDate" : '20-06-2019' }},
{"info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "ikl", },"date" : { "sDate" : '20-05-2019', "eDate" : '20-06-2019' }},{"info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "bbb", },"date" : { "sDate" : '20-05-2019', "eDate" : '20-06-2019' }},{"info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "bdd", },"date" : { "sDate" : '04-05-2019', "eDate" : '20-05-2019' }},];


 let out = array1.filter(({policy, date}) => array2.some(e => e.info.insuredPolicy === policy && e.date.sDate === date));
 console.log(out)
```

> EDIT: As per new requirement

you can write a method to get the previous date string as following

```js
const array1 = [{id: "1", policy: "abc", date: "20-05-2019" },{id: "4", policy: "hjk", date: "12-05-2019" },{id: "5", policy: "ikl", date: "08-05-2019" },{id: "7", policy: "qwe", date: "20-05-2019" },{id: "8", policy: "bdd", date: "04-05-2019" },]

const array2 = [{"info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "qwe", },"date" : { "sDate" : '21-05-2019', "eDate" : '20-06-2019' }},
{"info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "ikl", },"date" : { "sDate" : '20-05-2019', "eDate" : '20-06-2019' }},{"info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "bbb", },"date" : { "sDate" : '20-05-2019', "eDate" : '20-06-2019' }},{"info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "bdd", },"date" : { "sDate" : '04-05-2019', "eDate" : '20-05-2019' }},];


function yesterday(str) {
  return str.replace(/\d{2}/, (p1) => (p1 - 1).toString().padStart(2, 0))
}

let out = array1.filter(({policy, date}) => array2.some(e => e.info.insuredPolicy === policy && yesterday(e.date.sDate) === date));
 console.log(out)
```

Comment: A small edit required in question, need to reduce sDate one day & then compare with date. eg: if sDate is 05-05-2019, then reduce one day and compare with date in array1.

Comment: @Vishnu added the solution for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object as map and increment for the firts array and decrement for the second. At the end take only the keys with value zero and parse the key as JSON for a new object.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: "1", policy: "abc", date: "20-05-2019" }, { id: "4", policy: "hjk", date: "12-05-2019" }, { id: "5", policy: "ikl", date: "08-05-2019" }, { id: "7", policy: "qwe", date: "20-05-2019" }, { id: "8", policy: "bdd", date: "04-05-2019" }],
    array2 = [{ info: { insuredPolicy: "qwe" }, date: { sDate: "20-05-2019", eDate: "20-06-2019" } }, { info: { insuredPolicy: "ikl" }, date: { sDate: "20-05-2019", eDate: "20-06-2019" } }, { info: { insuredPolicy: "bbb" }, date: { sDate: "20-05-2019", eDate: "20-06-2019" } }, { info: { insuredPolicy: "bdd" }, date: { sDate: "04-05-2019", eDate: "20-05-2019" } }],
    wrapper1 = ({ policy, date }) => JSON.stringify({ policy, date }),
    wrapper2 = ({ info: { insuredPolicy: policy }, date: { sDate: date } }) => JSON.stringify({ policy, date }),
    map = Object.create(null),
    setMap = (map, wrapper, value) => object => (key => map[key] = (map[key] || 0) + value)(wrapper(object)),
    result;

array1.forEach(setMap(map, wrapper1, 1));
array2.forEach(setMap(map, wrapper2, -1));

result = Object
    .entries(map)
    .filter(([, v]) => !v)
    .map(([k]) => JSON.parse(k));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce()` to create new array based on your conditions

```js
var array1 = [
    {id: "1", policy: "abc", date: "20-05-2019" },
    {id: "4", policy: "hjk", date: "12-05-2019" },
    {id: "5", policy: "ikl", date: "08-05-2019" },
    {id: "7", policy: "qwe", date: "20-05-2019" },
    {id: "8", policy: "bdd", date: "04-05-2019" },
]

var array2 = [
 {
   "info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "qwe", },
   "date" : { "sDate" : "20-05-2019", "eDate" : "20-06-2019" }
 },
 {
   "info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "ikl", },
   "date" : { "sDate" : "20-05-2019", "eDate" : "20-06-2019" }
 },
{
   "info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "bbb", },
   "date" : { "sDate" : "20-05-2019", "eDate" : "20-06-2019" }
 },
{
   "info" : { "insuredPolicy" : "bdd", },
   "date" : { "sDate" : "04-05-2019", "eDate" : "20-05-2019" }
 },
];

console.log(array2.reduce((arr, { info: { insuredPolicy }, date: { sDate } }) => {
  var item = array1.find(({ policy, date }) => insuredPolicy == policy && sDate == date)
  if(item) arr.push({ policy: item.policy, date: item.date }) // edit as you want
  return arr
}, []))
```

Comment: A small edit required in question, need to reduce sDate one day & then compare with date. eg: if sDate is 05-05-2019, then reduce one day and compare with date in array1.